# genymotion doesn't match virtual device

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion, virtual-device-manager

Good day

after I update Genymotion...
[this massage appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/op9nz.png)

I tried to download the virtualBox 5.0.6 for windows from here  https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

but still the same problem,,

Does anyone have any idea..

Thank you

Comment: is your device working properly, after you click on continue?

Comment: yeah it's work but i can run my code

Comment: reinstall the device to get a compatible one.

Comment: still not working -_-